# Need to have lightbox thumbnail to resize when window shrinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a responsive portfolio and I'm at a standstill with my lightbox thumbnails. I need for the thumbnail to shrink with the rest of the site when the browser width is reduced but currently it just remains the same size. I'm not sure exactly where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated!

Link to Lightbox css file: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxgeLB33TSvCUWFvSVZWNTVidDQ&usp=sharing

Link to lightbox.js: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxgeLB33TSvCZUpYZG1TY3VXUjA/edit?usp=sharing

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Portofolio</title>
            <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
            </script>
            <link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />


</style>


    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
         <h1><a href="">NAME</a></h1>
        </div>
            <div id="nav">

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="content">

            <div class="article column1">
                <a href="images/article.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Article"> <img class="hoverme" src="images/2.jpg"></a>

            </div>
            <div class="article column2">
                <p>Column Two</p>
            </div>
            <div class="article column3">
                <p>Column Three</p>
            </div>
            <div class="article column1">
                <p>Column One</p>
            </div>
            <div class="article column2">
                <p>Column Two</p>
            </div>
            <div class="article column3">
                <p>Column Three</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p>Footer Text</p>
        </div>

        </div>

</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    @font-face { 
      font-family: 'bikoblack';
      src: url('fonts/biko_black.otf');
      }

        @font-face { 
      font-family: 'bikoregular';
      src: url('fonts/biko_regular.otf');
      }



a:link {
        color: #0f4c96;
    }
    a:visited {
        color: #0f4c96;
    }
    a:hover {
        color: #b2b1b1;
    }
    a:active {
        color: #0f4c96;
    }

    * {
        text-align: center;
        }
    body {

        margin: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        background-color: white;
         }
    #wrapper {
        max-width:90%;
        margin:0 auto;

    }



    h1 {
        font-family: 'bikoblack';
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 3.5em;
        line-height: 85%;
        color: #0f4c96;
        float: left;


        }
    #header {
        position:relative;
        overflow:hidden;
    }


    #nav {

        position:absolute;
        bottom:1.25em;
        right:1em;
        }
    li {
        display: inline;
        font-family: 'bikoregular';
        color: #0f4c96;
        padding-left: 2em;
        }


    #feature{

        background-color: #b2b1b1;
        padding: 5em;
        }

    .column1, .column2, .column3 {      
        width: 32.66%;
        float: left;
        margin: 1% 1% 1% 0;
        background-color: #b2b1b1;
        }       
    .column3 {
        margin-right: 0%;}
        }
    #feature, .article {
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        }

@media (max-width:767px) {
    h1 {
        float: none;
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
        }
    #nav {
        position:static;
        width:100%;margin:0 auto;
        top: 5em;
    }    
        li {
        width:100px;
        padding: 0 1em; 
    }
}

@media (max-width:480px){
    li {
        display:block;
        text-align:center;
        width:auto;
    }
}

a {text-decoration: none; }
```

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle or provide code that is more easily copied and pasted for set up in a test server. i.e.: lightbox.css is not given as a repository link or provided; you left it as an assumption that style.css is the CSS code sample provided. You will get better answers if you are more concise.

Comment: Sorry, I did not think of that. Here is the lightbox css file: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxgeLB33TSvCUWFvSVZWNTVidDQ&usp=sharing

Comment: Just added the lightbox.css in the fiddle, still working. Now only the js is missing.

Comment: I'm an idiot! Sorry! https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxgeLB33TSvCZUpYZG1TY3VXUjA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: np ;). Doesn't work to include js from there, guess it would be easier if you just check if adding the css for img width and/or height would work for you or not. Will check to either find this lightbox.js online to include it or down- + upload it.

Comment: Good news (hope so) - just added the lightbox.css + js in the fiddle and it's still resizing the thumbnail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/2mdLouf4/) with the only adjustment to add

```
img {width: 100%; height: 100%;}
```

so the img resizes.
Not sure if this works for you as the js etc. is missing, but you could give it a try.
In case this won't work because possibly the lightbox.css which is missing in the fiddle overwrites these values, you could e.g. try to set height and width: 100% !important. In case the values for the thumbnails would be set by the lightbox.js, you should inspect the DOM with a web developer tool like e.g. Firebug to check which values (if any) are set to the thumbnails.
Update: lightbox.css and .js added to the Fiddle, still resizing the thumbnail image.
As you probably already know but should be added as short explanation: if the img is assigned 100% width and height, but is located in a container element with responsive size, the img will just get as big as the container.

Update: As already tested, setting the image height and width to 100% is not enough as the thumbnail image is displayed too big. Therefore it's necessary to add appropriate `max-width` to the container of the image. In the example provided, the image inherits the max size from the div with the class `.column1`; it might be necessary to add this not only for `.column1`, but to the styles for `.column1, .column2, .column3 { ....}` as they're already having the same styles and maybe are used as container for additional thumbnail-images.

Comment: When I set the image width and height to 100% the height is way off from what I'm trying to accomplish. Here is what I get: http://i.imgur.com/UmXHMKl.jpg And this is what I am going for: http://imgur.com/7uZiZmn

Comment: ok, but is it responsive like in the fiddle? if yes, then it's only a question of setting appropriate max-width / height for the container (because of the limited space in jsfiddle I only added a small image, therefore it looks nearly ok there)

Comment: just changed the dummy-img in the fiddle to 400x400px and made a quick test; I guess you have to adjust the css for .column1, .column2, .column3 {..}; just add there the max-width depending on the max img size; tested it with 200px but maybe you would like to have it smaller. The img inherits its max size from these .column-container(s).